# Parsing Custom DateTime Format

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, datetime

I have to parse `DateTime` objects from strings with the `yyyyMMddhhmmss` format.

If I run this code, it works fine:

```
DateTime y = new DateTime(2013, 07, 22, 15, 35, 23);
string x = y.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But if I run this code - seemingly the inverse operation - I get an exception:

```
string x = "20130722153523";
DateTime y = DateTime.ParseExact(x, "yyyyMMddhhmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The exception is:

```
System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

I'm stumped as to what's wrong here. What am I doing wrong?

*Note: Don't worry about timezones. I can deal with getting the correct timezone later.*

Comment: In first code sample x is 20130722033523, not 20130722153523

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is that the date-time format you specified uses `hh` for a 12-hour time format, but the input string has `15` in that area. It can't parse this because 15 is outside the expected range.

Try using `HH` for a  24-hour time format instead:

```
string x = "20130722153523";
DateTime y = DateTime.ParseExact(x, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**Further Reading:**

- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: Straight from MSDN: If format is a custom format pattern that does not include date or time separators (such as "yyyyMMdd HHmm"), use the invariant culture for the provider parameter and the widest form of each custom format specifier. For example, if you want to specify hours in the format pattern, specify the wider form, "HH", instead of the narrower form, "H".

Comment: +1. Also check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx - (quote) **Notes to Callers**: 
In the .NET Framework 4, the ParseExact method throws a FormatException if the string to be parsed contains an hour component and an AM/PM designator that are not in agreement. In the .NET Framework 3.5 and earlier versions, the AM/PM designator is ignored.(/quote)

Comment: Any idea of how to make it understand the end part of `"12-Sep-2015 08:12:54 UTC"` or any location instead of UTC?